# How to get the degree of a node in Cytoscape

Tags: java, cytoscape

i'm trying to figure out how to get the degree of a node in my network? I was reading through the [Cytoscape_3_App_Cookbook](http://wiki.cytoscape.org/Cytoscape_3/AppDeveloper/Cytoscape_3_App_Cookbook#How_to_get_all_the_nodes_with_a_specific_attribute_value.3F), however I wasn't able to find what I was looking for.

Any suggestions/resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

int nodeDegree = networkView.getModel().getAdjacentEdgeList(nodes.getModel(),
CyEdge.Type.ANY).size();